# Disable the close button of a window in Windows

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a program for Windows that can disable the close button of a window. If possible, gratis, provides a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable the close button, and can remember on which windows the close button has been disabled when the corresponding application is started again.

Comment: I had the same question, how to disabled the close button of a specific program. NoClose works fine on Win 7, but it doesn't work on Win 11, which is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NoClose](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose):

- gratis and open-source (AHK-based)
- provides a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable the close button
- can remember on which windows the close button has been disabled when the corresponding application is started again.
- works in Windows 7
- does not work with some customized windows such as Google Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
;NoClose.ahk
; Disable the Close button (X) of selected windows
; To run, save to BlockInput.ahk and install AutoHotkey from www.autohotkey.com
;Skrommel @2006

#SingleInstance,Force
SetTitleMatchMode,2

applicationname=NoClose

ids=
oldids=

Gosub,INIREAD
Gosub,TRAYMENU
Gosub,STARTUP
OnExit,EXIT
Hotkey,%add%,ADD
Hotkey,%swap%,SWAP

Loop
{
  Sleep,500
  allids=
  activeids=
  WinGet,id_,List,,,Program Manager
  Loop,%id_%
  {
    Sleep,0
    id:=id_%A_Index%
    allids=%allids%%id%`,
    IfInString,ids,%id%`,
      activeids=%activeids%%id%`,
    If autodisable=0
      Continue
    IfInString,oldids,%id%`,
      Continue
    WinGetTitle,title,ahk_id %id%
    WinGetClass,class,ahk_id %id%
    rule=%title% ahk_class %class%|||
    IfInString,rules,%rule%
    {
      DISABLE(id)
      activeids=%activeids%%id%`,
    }
  }
  oldids:=allids
  ids:=activeids
}
Return


STARTUP:
allids=
WinGet,id_,List,,,Program Manager
Loop,%id_%
{
  id:=id_%A_Index%
  allids=%allids%%id%`,
  If disableonstartup=0
    Continue
  WinGetTitle,title,ahk_id %id%
  WinGetClass,class,ahk_id %id%
  rule=%title% ahk_class %class%|||
  IfInString,rules,%rule%
  {
    DISABLE(id)
    ids=%ids%%id%`,
  }
}
oldids:=allids
Return


EXIT:
If enableonexit=0
  ExitApp
WinGet,id_,List,,,Program Manager
Loop,%id_%
{
  id:=id_%A_Index%
  IfInString,ids,%id%`,
  {
    ENABLE(id)
    StringReplace,ids,ids,%id%`,,
  }
}
ExitApp


ADD:
WinGet,id,ID,A
WinGetTitle,title,ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass,class,ahk_id %id%
rule=%title% ahk_class %class%|||
IfInString,rules,%rule%
  Return
Else
{
  DISABLE(id)
  rules=%rules%%rule%
  ids=%ids%%id%`,
  IniWrite,%rules%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,rules
}
Return


SWAP:
WinGet,id,ID,A
WinGetTitle,title,ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass,class,ahk_id %id%
IfInString,ids,%id%`,
{
  ENABLE(id)
  StringReplace,ids,ids,%id%`,,
  Return
}
DISABLE(id)
ids=%ids%%id%`,
Return


DISABLE(id) ;By RealityRipple at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-258725.html
{
  menu:=DllCall("user32\GetSystemMenu","UInt",id,"UInt",0)
  DllCall("user32\DeleteMenu","UInt",menu,"UInt",0xF060,"UInt",0x0)
  WinGetPos,x,y,w,h,ahk_id %id%
  WinMove,ahk_id %id%,,%x%,%y%,%w%,% h-1
  WinMove,ahk_id %id%,,%x%,%y%,%w%,% h+1
}


ENABLE(id) ;By Mosaic1 at http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-258725.html
{
  menu:=DllCall("user32\GetSystemMenu","UInt",id,"UInt",1)
  DllCall("user32\DrawMenuBar","UInt",id)
}


TRAYMENU:
Menu,Tray,NoStandard 
Menu,Tray,DeleteAll 
Menu,Tray,Add,%applicationname%,ABOUT
Menu,Tray,Add,
Menu,Tray,Add,&Settings...,SETTINGS
Menu,Tray,Add,&About...,ABOUT
Menu,Tray,Add,E&xit,EXIT
Menu,Tray,Default,%applicationname%
Menu,Tray,Tip,%applicationname%
Return


INIREAD:
IfNotExist,%applicationname%.ini
{
  disableonstartup=1
  autodisable=1
  enableonexit=1
  swap=^1
  add=^2
  rules=
  Gosub,INIWRITE
  Gosub,ABOUT
}
IniRead,disableonstartup,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,disableonstartup
IniRead,autodisable,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,autodisable
IniRead,enableonexit,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,enableonexit
IniRead,swap,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,swap
IniRead,add,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,add
IniRead,rules,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,rules
Return


INIWRITE:
IniWrite,%disableonstartup%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,disableonstartup
IniWrite,%autodisable%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,autodisable
IniWrite,%enableonexit%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,enableonexit
IniWrite,%swap%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,swap
IniWrite,%add%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,add
IniWrite,%rules%,%applicationname%.ini,Settings,rules
Return


SETTINGS:
HotKey,%swap%,Off
HotKey,%add%,Off
Gui,Destroy
Gui,Add,Tab,W340 H330 xm,Options|Rules
Gui,Tab,1
Gui,Add,GroupBox,xm+10 ym+40 w320 h70,&Hotkey to Enable/Disable the active windows' close button
Gui,Add,Hotkey,xp+10 yp+20 w300 vsswap
StringReplace,current,swap,+,Shift +%A_Space%
StringReplace,current,current,^,Ctrl +%A_Space%
StringReplace,current,current,!,Alt +%A_Space%
Gui,Add,Text,xm+20 y+5,Current hotkey: %current%

Gui,Add,GroupBox,xm+10 y+30 w320 h70,Hotkey to &Add a new rule
Gui,Add,Hotkey,xm+20 yp+20 w300 vsadd
StringReplace,current,add,+,Shift +%A_Space%
StringReplace,current,current,^,Ctrl +%A_Space%
StringReplace,current,current,!,Alt +%A_Space%
Gui,Add,Text,xm+20 y+5,Current hotkey: %current%

Gui,Add,GroupBox,xm+10 y+30 w320 h80,Automatic rule execution
Gui,Add,CheckBox,xm+20 yp+20 Checked%disableonstartup% vsdisableonstartup,Disable close buttons on NoClose &Startup
Gui,Add,CheckBox,xm+20 y+5 Checked%autodisable% vsautodisable,Disable close buttons on &Window Creation
Gui,Add,CheckBox,xm+20 y+5 Checked%enableonexit% vsenableonexit,Enable close buttons on NoClose &Exit

Gui,Tab,2
StringReplace,rules,rules,|||,`n,All
Gui,Add,GroupBox,w320 h280 xm+10 y+10,&Windows Titles and Classes
Gui,Add,Edit,xm+20 yp+20 w300 h180 Multi -Wrap vsrules,%rules%
Gui,Add,Text,xm+20 y+5,Syntax: <Part of a Window Title> <ahk_class Class Name>
Gui,Add,Text,xm+20 y+5,Example: Calculator ahk_class SciCalc   
Gui,Add,Text,xm+30 y+5,will disable all Calculator close buttons.
Gui,Add,Text,xm+20 y+5,Either part is optional.

Gui,Tab
Gui,Add,Button,xm+10 y+30 w75 GSETTINGSOK,&OK
Gui,Add,Button,x+5 w75 GSETTINGSCANCEL,&Cancel
Gui,Show,,%applicationname% Settings
Return

SETTINGSOK:
Gui,Submit
If sswap<>
{
  swap:=sswap
  HotKey,%swap%,SWAP
}
HotKey,%swap%,On
If sadd<>
{
  add:=sadd
  HotKey,%add%,ADD
}
HotKey,%add%,On
If sdelay<>
  delay:=sdelay
StringReplace,rules,srules,`n,|||,All
rules=%rules%|||
Loop
{
  StringReplace,rules,rules,||||||,|||,All
  StringGetPos,pos,rules,||||||
  If pos<0
    Break
}
StringLeft,start,rules,3
If start=|||
  StringTrimLeft,rules,rules,3
disableonstartup:=sdisableonstartup
autodisable:=sautodisable
enableonexit:=senableonexit
Gosub,INIWRITE
Return

SETTINGSCANCEL:
HotKey,%swap%,SWAP
HotKey,%swap%,On
HotKey,%add%,ADD
HotKey,%add%,On
Gui,Destroy
Return


ABOUT:
Gui,99:Destroy
Gui,99:Margin,20,20
Gui,99:Add,Picture,xm Icon1,%applicationname%.exe
Gui,99:Font,Bold
Gui,99:Add,Text,x+10 yp+10,%applicationname% v1.1
Gui,99:Font
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,Disable the Close button (X) of selected windows.
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,- Press Ctrl+1 to Enable or Disable a close button.
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+5 ,- Press Ctrl+2 to Add a rule.
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,- To change the settings, choose Settings in the tray menu.

Gui,99:Add,Picture,xm y+20 Icon5,%applicationname%.exe
Gui,99:Font,Bold
Gui,99:Add,Text,x+10 yp+10,1 Hour Software by Skrommel
Gui,99:Font
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,For more tools, information and donations, please visit 
Gui,99:Font,CBlue Underline
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+5 G1HOURSOFTWARE,www.1HourSoftware.com
Gui,99:Font

Gui,99:Add,Picture,xm y+20 Icon7,%applicationname%.exe
Gui,99:Font,Bold
Gui,99:Add,Text,x+10 yp+10,DonationCoder
Gui,99:Font
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,Please support the contributors at
Gui,99:Font,CBlue Underline
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+5 GDONATIONCODER,www.DonationCoder.com
Gui,99:Font

Gui,99:Add,Picture,xm y+20 Icon6,%applicationname%.exe
Gui,99:Font,Bold
Gui,99:Add,Text,x+10 yp+10,AutoHotkey
Gui,99:Font
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+10,This tool was made using the powerful
Gui,99:Font,CBlue Underline
Gui,99:Add,Text,y+5 GAUTOHOTKEY,www.AutoHotkey.com
Gui,99:Font

Gui,99:Show,,%applicationname% About
hCurs:=DllCall("LoadCursor","UInt",NULL,"Int",32649,"UInt") ;IDC_HAND
OnMessage(0x200,"WM_MOUSEMOVE") 
Return

1HOURSOFTWARE:
  Run,http://www.1hoursoftware.com,,UseErrorLevel
Return

DONATIONCODER:
  Run,http://www.donationcoder.com,,UseErrorLevel
Return

AUTOHOTKEY:
  Run,http://www.autohotkey.com,,UseErrorLevel
Return

99GuiClose:
  Gui,99:Destroy
  OnMessage(0x200,"")
  DllCall("DestroyCursor","Uint",hCur)
Return

WM_MOUSEMOVE(wParam,lParam)
{
  Global hCurs
  MouseGetPos,,,,ctrl
  If ctrl in Static10,Static14,Static18
    DllCall("SetCursor","UInt",hCurs)
  Return
}
Return
```

Answer (score 2):

I used software listed at https://www.raymond.cc/blog/prevent-program-closing-disabling-close-button/

1. NoClose (did not work for me)
2. WinTopMost (expensive, did not try)
3. Actual Window Guard (not free, but has a trial and works, even on Chrome, can be configured with various process and or window filters)
4. Actual Window Manager (same as above, but more expensive with more additional features)
5. NoVirusThanks Process Protector (no trial, did not try)

So my choice was https://www.actualtools.com/windowguard/